# Check if user is on a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a select_tag which is displaying all the `users` from my db, when selected is sending the user to `users/1..n`.

How can I check if the users is on page `users/1` or `users/2`. I need this because I want to display different things if the user is on those pages.

A solution that I thought about is to render a different `layout` but it seems to much work to only hide or display 5 divs.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the helper `current_page?` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.original_url` to return the path that's been requested.  from the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url):

```
# get "/articles?page=2"
request.original_url # => "http://www.example.com/articles?page=2"
```

you could then do something like this:

controller:

```
@user = current_user
@current_page = request.original_url
```

view:

```
<%= do [this stuff] if @current_page.include?("users/x") %>
```

if you want to check if the user is on their *own* page you could try this:

```
<%= do [my own page stuff] if @current_page.include?("users/#{@user.id}") %>
```